# Sending SELECT @ variable from SQL to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

I have this statement that's working well in SQL:

```
SET @cnt = (SELECT `reg_date` FROM logindb WHERE `userlogin`='urs'); 
SET @var = (SELECT TIME (@cnt)); 
SELECT @var
```

But I don't know how to get that data if I don't have a specific column output.

In php I'm trying with the following code:

```
$sql = "SET @cnt = (SELECT `reg_date` FROM logindb WHERE `userlogin`='urs'); 
SET @var = (SELECT TIME (@cnt)); 
SELECT @var"
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo($row["@var"]);
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\DAN\autentificare.php on line 62

The line 62 :

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

I don't know how to store or view that variable in PHP.

Explanation of the code:
When I created the table named logindb, I use a variable reg_date declared as TIMESTAMP that put the server time every time another column from the same line is filled. To resume the entire code is used to get only the TIME from reg_date : Ex. 2015-01-06 00:39:56 output that I get in @var is 00:39:56

Comment: THe problem is that query wont be able to run multiple statements.Use mysql_multi_query for that

Comment: I thing you're right, because I have other 2 queries upper than this one.
I''ll try and get back here with the results.
But I don't know how to implement this :)
I will search.

Comment: yea.. this is the issue. And I don't know how to apply to more that 2 queries..

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT @var as colName
....
echo($row["colName"]);
```

**UPDATE**

When I read the post first time I think that the question is something simplified. Anyway, to solve your issue you can use this code.

```
$sql = "SELECT TIME(`reg_date`) FROM logindb WHERE `userlogin`='urs'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo $result->fetch_row[0];
```

Comment: sorry, I thought the last line was the issue, but is the line with this statement **$row = $result->fetch_assoc();**
Any idea?

Comment: So, the above solution doesn't work. I get the error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\DAN\autentificare.php on line 62

Answer (score 0):

The following code(assuming your $sql statement is valid)

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Returns an associative array.  To access the value the key would look likethis:

```
$myresult = $row['column'];
```

*column is the column you selected in your statement, in your case 'reg_date'

Comment: at that line **$row = $result->fetch_assoc();** I have the issue

Comment: $sql = SELECT `reg_date` FROM logindb WHERE `userlogin`='urs'; this is a complete statement. Explain what you are trying to get from the database.  Example: I want to get the values of certain cells.  or I want to update certain cell values. I'm having trouble understanding what you want the code to do.

Comment: When I created the table named logindb, I use a variable reg_date declared as TIMESTAMP that put the server time every time another column from the same line is filled.
To resume the entire code is used to get only the TIME from reg_date :
Ex. 2015-01-06 00:39:56  output that I get in @var is 00:39:56